# Normal Probability Plot: points oscillate around line of slope 1: polynomial?

Tags: statistics, regression

This is the Normal Probability Plot I've obtained for some data:

[image: plot]

As you can see the points seem to osciallate, as in a period, around the line of slope 1 and passing through the origin. I've obtained this plot by trying to fit a simple linear regression model. Can I deduce from this peculiar behaviour (just as an Anzat, or a guess, waiting for further tests) that this can indicate that there is a polynomial relationship? (for example the grade of the polynomial might be equal to the number of times the oscillation crosses the line)

Or otherwise, what does this suggest? That there is a trigonometric relationship?

**Edit**

Basically Ive fitted a linear model `data.lm <- lm(y~x, data=data)` , then Ive created the standardized residuals `data.lm$sr <- rstandard(data.lm)` and finally plotted the qqplot `qqnorm(data.lm$sr)` and I've added `abline(0,1)`

Comment: The 'variation' around the line is random, and I see no point in further analysis. If you want a formal test of normality use Shapiro-Wilk (`shapiro.test` in R) or some other test of normality. You cannot expect residuals to fall _exactly_ on the line, even if errors in the model are normal.

Comment: To get an idea how variable results are for truly normal data, in R you can execute the following code several times: `x = rnorm(28); qqnorm(x);  qqline(x)`.

Comment: @BruceET okay thank you. I'm still not that expert with qqplots. If you write an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Thanks; happy enough without 'credit' for an Answer, if you've got the point.